# Return a soap fault from spring ws

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-ws

I'm looking for some way to respond to a SOAP request with a soap fault.

Right now I can only create a fault when an exception is thrown via an `AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver`.

I have looked at an `EndpointInterceptorAdapter` but I'm not sure how to inspect or modify the response. For instance if an endpoint returns a `ValidResponse` but there were no values found or returned in a list in the response I would like to respond to the users request with a `SoapFault` instead.

We make efforts to follow "Don't Use Exceptions For Flow Control" but I've been un-successful with creating a `SoapFault` from an interceptor or from the endpoint without throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think `AbstractValidatingInterceptor` comes to the rescue. At least from source code part: how to handle response from `interceptor` and how to deal with `WebServiceMessage response`.

Bear in mind, the `WebServiceMessage` can be cast to the `SoapMessage` and you can populate your custom `SoapFault` using its `SoapBody`:

```
SoapBody soapBody = ((SoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse()).getSoapBody();
```